# GD Changing Black To White

Tags: php, apache, gd

After moving our website from CentOS to Ubuntu, using GD results in black/dark colors becoming white.

The code is exactly identical on both systems and file permissions are the same.

The configuration files, as far as I can see in PHP.ini and Apache are the same as well.

On the CentOS server, we're using PHP 5.1.6 and Apache 2.2.3.  On the Ubuntu server we're using PHP 5.5.9 and Apache 2.4.7 but I can't find any documentation that would describe the difference.  Both servers have the GD library installed.

Am I missing something?  Is there an obscure configuration file or known issue that I'm encountering?

Here's an example of what the white splotches look like:

[image]

Comment: Does the version of GD differ between the servers? [romanenko.alex.v's comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php#115839) at the PHP `imagecolortransparent` documentation mentions a difference in behavior in the transparancy color between different versions of GD.

Comment: CentOS had 2.0.28 and the Ubuntu server has 2.1.1-dev.  It looks like the issue may be related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was caused by the differences in how GD was handling transparency.  The code was setting RGB(0,0,0) to transparent.  For some reason on the old server this wasn't an issue.